# Clojure: Lein run unable to resolve symbol

Tags: clojure

I just started on my first clojure project using lein, the code here:

```
(ns fileops.core
  (:use
    [clojure.core :only (slurp)]
    [clojure-csv.core :only (parse-csv)]
    [fileops.core]))

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (read-file "sample.csv"))

(defn read-file
  "open and read the csv file"
  [fname]
  (with-open [file (clojure.java.io/reader fname)]
    (parse-csv (slurp fname))))
```

I tried to run this using "lein run" but I keep getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: read-file in this context
    at clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException(Util.java:219)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.resolveIn(Compiler.java:6874)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.resolve(Compiler.java:6818)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSymbol(Compiler.java:6779)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6343)
    ... 52 more
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: read-file should be before main in your source.

Comment: @DiegoBasch you're a life saver. I'm new to Clojure and I spent way too much time trying to figure out why I was getting an error about my function being called in the wrong context. This was it... This was it the whole time. Great post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have used *only* slurp from clojure core, meaning that every other core function is now unavailable to you :) Try changing your `ns` to use `:require` instead of `:use`, as this is more idiomatic.

One thing to note is that order does matter in clojure, so if you don't declare a function at the top of your file, as in C and some other languages, the earlier functions will not be able to make reference to them. This is what was causing your error before and is why I like to define my `-main` function at the bottom. It's a matter of style.

Another thing is that your `-main` function is taking variable args right now and not using them. In Clojure it is idiomatic to use `_` to refer to a parameter that doesn't get used. You could use `& _` to avoid error messages, for when the user passes in unnecessary args, but I would just have the -main function parameterless from the start. This is because nothing needs to be provided to main when you run the program, and errors do make debugging easier. It is good to know what is getting used and where. The `sample.csv` file is already provided and is having `read-file` called on it, so the program should run if your `read-file` function is correct and the `sample.csv` file is in the proper location.

Regarding your `-main` function, it would be nice to put a little test in there to see if it executes properly when you run it, so I changed it to print out the contents of the csv file onto your console. This way of printing from a file is efficient and worth studying in its own right.

Finally, Make sure you include `clojure-csv.core` in your `project.clj` file.

core.clj:

```
(ns fileops.core
  (:require
    [clojure-csv.core :refer [parse-csv]]))

(defn read-file
  "open and read the csv file"
  [fname]
  (with-open [file (clojure.java.io/reader fname)]
    (parse-csv (slurp fname)))) 

 (defn -main []
        (println (clojure.string/join "\n" (read-file "resources/test.csv"))))
```

project.clj:

```
...

:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
               [clojure-csv/clojure-csv "2.0.1"]
                ...]
:main fileops.core
```

You need to declare fileops.core as :main, as shown above. This tells Leiningen what function to execute when you enter `lein run`. Very important and tricky stuff.

So now make sure you are in the root of your project directory and at the terminal, run the following:

```
lein clean
lein deps 
lein run
```

Good luck!

**Further reading:**

[8th light blog on name-spaces](http://blog.8thlight.com/colin-jones/2010/12/05/clojure-libs-and-namespaces-require-use-import-and-ns.html)

[flying machine studios explanation of `lein run`](http://www.flyingmachinestudios.com/programming/how-clojure-babies-are-made-lein-run/)

Answer (score 1):

read-file should be before main in your source OR you should put before -main a declare cause like that:

```
(declare read-file)
```